# Need help understanding this implementation of tetris

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to understand [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dac9b4db7b843e4b1e519ce1d1dbe28c) implementation of Tetris.

I have a few questions.

In update_score function,

```
 if (( score > LEVEL_UP * level)) ; then          # if level should be increased
    ((level++))                                  # increment level
    pkill -SIGUSR1 -f "/bin/bash $0"
```

What is the use of having a separate process at all for adjusting the delay? Why use `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`?

In the draw_piece function, why multiply by 8? I don't understand how the conversion is taking place or how the concept of "rotation" is implemented here.

```
for ((i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)) {
    # relative coordinates are retrieved based on orientation and added to absolute coordinates
    ((x = $1 + ${piece[$3]:$((i + $4 * 8 + 1)):1} * 2))
    ((y = $2 + ${piece[$3]:$((i + $4 * 8)):1}))
    xyprint $x $y "$5"

    ...
}
```

Nor do I understand the syntax involving     : here.

In clear_next, why is draw_next `${filled_cell//?/ }` necessary instead of just `${filled_cell}`? What do the `//` signify?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm a beginner to shell scripting and programming in general and I have been trying to understand this implementation of Tetris *[in shell]*

Somehow, I suspect you could have found easier programs to start with.

> What is the use of having a separate process at all for adjusting the delay? Why use [SIGUSR1] and [SIGUSR2]?

I don't think there's a separate process for *adjusting* the delay, but for *implementing* the timer. The timer must run even while the program is waiting for the player to give input, and if the shell functions don't give any way of having a timeout on `read`, that must be exported to another process. So then you get what there is in the end of script, a divide into the timer, the user input handler, and the actual game logic, with output from the first two going to the last one:

```
(ticker & reader) | (controller)
```

Bash's `read` does have the `-t` flag for timeout, so if it was implemented in Bash, you might not need the extra timer process. However, putting the timer in an external process also makes it independent of the user input, the `read` timeout would instead reset every time user hits a button. Working around that would require some way of accurately determining the elapsed time (or using a really short timeout on `read` and counting the ticks).

`SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` are just "innocent" signals that don't have a meaning to the system at large, so they can be used here. Of course you could use others, but catching `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP` would annoy users if they wanted to stop the game.

> In the draw_piece function, why multiply by 8?
>
> ```
>  ((x = $1 + ${piece[$3]:$((i + $4 * 8 + 1)):1} * 2))
> ```

The `piece` array contains the different shapes and orientations of the pieces. A piece is 4 squares large, each square needs two coordinates, so we get 8 numbers per piece/orientation. For, example, the string for the S piece is `0001111201101120`, so it has two orientations:

```
yx yx yx yx   yx yx yx yx
00 01 11 12   01 10 11 20
```

And the piece looks something like this:

```
  012      012
0 xx.    0 .x.
1 .xx    1 xx.
2 ...    2 x..
```

The `${variable:position:length}` notation picks a substring from the given variable, so the program gets the single digits it needs from the bigger string. That's a somewhat weird way of implementing an array.

> In clear_next, why is draw_next `${filled_cell//?/ }` necessary ...? What do the `//` signify?

The `${parameter/foo/bar}` construct is a pattern replacement (See e.g. [Bash's manual on parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), look for "replace"). Whatever matches `foo` in the value of `parameter`, is replaced with `bar`, and the result is expanded. With a double slash, all matches are replaced, with a single slash, only the first. The question mark matches any character as with filename globs, so that effectively makes a string of spaces as long as the original string.

For example:

```
$ str="hallo hallo"
$ echo "${str/a/e}"
hello hallo
$ echo "${str//a/e}"
hello hello
$ str="abc"
$ echo "x${str//?/ }x"
x   x
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the syntax of the statement involving the : where it is trying to assign the coordinates? That seems to be a common element in the program and I can't interpret it in terms of if-else

Comment: @Enne, the `${::}`? substring. edited. same page of the Bash manual.

Comment: Running the timer in a separate process is not much use as the trap handler is not executed before the `read` returns. But I admit that shells other than `bash` may handle that differently.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, huh, seems to me that the trap handler runs immediately, even if there is a `read` waiting, on Bash 4.4 at least. Something like `bash -c 'trap "echo trapped" SIGUSR1; read x; echo "x: $x"'` and then `pkill -USR1 -f "bash.*trap"` in another window

Comment: @HaukeLaging, and also, as far as I understood, the program doesn't try to interrupt any reads through the timer signal, the timer process just prints out commands to the controller through the pipe, the same way as the user input process. The only thing the signals do (apart from exiting) is to recalculate the delay, and of course that only takes effect after the previous sleep is complete.

Comment: It seems that this from the man page refers to external commands only, not to builtins: "If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes."

Comment: So what could be an alternative way to get the trick done in bash? Can we do it without the signals at all, just in a normal program?